# How Can I Launch My Flutter App that connects a serve I have coded in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, client, hosting

I have created an app that connects to a serve on my localhost and sende/receives data.I use mongodb as database and everything works perefectly in the localhost.However I want to server run 7/24 and being connected from all the users.How should I make the server run 7/24 and be reachable from any wifi ?

Comment: I think your question is not flutter related. And moreover it is not completely clear. What is the problem? To have a server 24/7 working purchase a web hosting with mongodb installed (or install by yourself). Flutter app can connect any IP address you point in settings of HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a "Flutter" question, but anyway, you should explore your options, depending on what you need from a server, check out AWS (Amazon Web Services), Google Cloud Run and such. Also Google owned Firebase - it has nice services with a reasonable free tier.

I also used MongoDB for my backend on a private server, but then switched to Firebase (Firestore in particular) and it works just fine for what I need.